Equivalent solutions to $\int \frac1{1-\frac1{\phi}\sin x}dx$
I worked through the integration of
$$\int \frac1{1-\frac1{\phi}\sin x}dx$$
with the tangent half-angle substitution and obtained the solution
$$2\sqrt{\phi}\tan^{-1}\frac{\phi\tan\frac x2-1}{\sqrt{\phi}}
$$
However, my reference source lists has it as
$$\sqrt{\phi} \tan^{-1}\frac{\tan x}{\sqrt{\phi}}-\sqrt{\phi} \tan^{-1}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{\phi}}
$$
So, I would expect a constant between the two, which I was able to see from a WA graph. I was also able to infer from the point $x=0$ that the constant is $\sqrt{\phi}\ \text{arccot} \sqrt{\phi} $, but unable to derive from the two solutions.
Given above background, my question is: how to show the equality
$$\tan^{-1}\frac{\tan x}{\sqrt{\phi}}-\tan^{-1}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{\phi}}  -2 \tan^{-1}\frac{\phi\tan\frac x2-1}{\sqrt{\phi}} = \tan^{-1}\frac1{ \sqrt{\phi} } $$

Did you try using the identity for sum of inverse tangents?

Yves is correct

Constant cancelling in a definite integral is immaterial to the question, which is to show the equality above.

At least for, say $0<x<\frac\pi2$, you can apply the identities$$2\arctan\frac t{1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\arctan t\\arctan u \pm\arctan v=\arctan\frac{u\pm v}{1\mp uv}$$to combine into one $\arctan$. The result involves a very hairy argument that indeed (judging by a plot with the naked eye) magically reduces to a constant.

Let $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\dfrac1{\sqrt\phi} \left(\tan x, \cos x, \phi\tan\dfrac x2-1\right)$. Recall the double-angle identity,
$$2\arctan\frac \delta{1+\sqrt{1+\delta}} = \arctan \delta.$$
Set the $\arctan$ argument on the left side to $\gamma$ and solve for $\delta$; one finds
$$\delta = -2\sqrt\phi \frac{1-\phi\tan\frac x2}{\phi - \left(1-\phi\tan\frac x2\right)^2}.$$
If $0<x<\dfrac\pi2$ (and possibly beyond this domain), then we can combine the three $\arctan$s into one using the sum identity,
$$\arctan u \pm \arctan v = \arctan \frac{u\pm v}{1\mp uv}$$
$$\begin{align*}
\implies & \arctan \alpha - \arctan \beta - 2\arctan \gamma \\
&= \arctan \alpha - \arctan \beta - \arctan \delta \\
&= \arctan \frac{\alpha - \beta - \delta - \alpha\beta\delta}{1 + \alpha\beta + \alpha\delta-\beta\delta}
\end{align*}.$$
Match up the arguments and the problem boils down to showing that
$$\frac{\alpha - \beta - \delta - \alpha\beta\delta}{1 + \alpha\beta + \alpha\delta-\beta\delta} = \frac1{\sqrt\phi}$$
or upon replacing $\alpha,\beta,\delta$ and simplifying, that
$$\frac{2f(x)g(x) + h(x) \left(\phi - f(x)^2\right)}{-2f(x)h(x) + \frac1\phi g(x) \left(\phi - f(x)^2\right)}=1 \tag1$$
$$\implies \frac{2f(x)}{\phi - f(x)^2} = \frac{\frac1\phi g(x) - h(x)}{g(x) + h(x)} \tag2$$
where
$$\begin{cases}
f(x)=1-\phi\tan\dfrac x2 \\
g(x)=\phi+\sin x \\
h(x)=\tan x-\cos x
\end{cases} \quad .$$
Rewrite everything on the RHS of $(2)$ in terms of half-angle arguments. I abbreviate with $c=\cos\dfrac x2$ and $s=\sin\dfrac x2$.
$$\frac{2 \left(1 - \phi \frac sc\right)}{\phi-\left(1-\phi\frac sc\right)^2} = \frac{1+\left(c^2-s^2\right)+\frac2\phi cs - \frac{2cs}{c^2-s^2}}{\phi - \left(c^2-s^2\right) + 2cs + \frac{2cs}{c^2-s^2}} \tag3$$
Subtract the RHS from the LHS, join the fractions, and simplify. The numerator of the resulting expression vanishes:
$$\frac{\overbrace{\left(\phi^2-\phi-1\right)}^{=0} c \left(c^2 - s^2 - 2cs\right)}{2\phi \left(2c^2+2cs-\phi\right) \left(4c^4 - 4c^3s-(2\phi+4)c^2+\phi^2\right)}$$
